# How are people able to procure sounds from electromagnetic waves?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, acoustics, electromagnetic-induction

I have found out about this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lO5ehpdZ5Po, and also this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cga3DfaLc7A.

The first one is about a device called the Elektrosluch (electrical hearing), which captures the electromagnetical fields via two inductors, amplifies them via an op amp, and outputs them to a stereo jack (from [here](https://makezine.com/projects/weekend-project-sample-weird-sounds-electromagnetic-fields/%22)). It outputs some pretty interesting sounds.

The second video is a recording of supposedly "Neptune's EM sounds" (I haven't been able to verify this claim, though.). It seems pretty close to the Elektrosluch video, so I think it would be real.

Finally, I am pretty interested in the physics behind this. I have some basics of this laid out in my mind, but I hope a more experienced physicist would be able to help me!

Answer (score 1):

Electromagnetic waves at extra-low frequencies do exist, and the devices you mention are basically radio receivers tuned for the lowest of the low-frequency waves out there- which are in the range of audio frequencies your ears can hear. The radio receiver picks up the electromagnetic waves, amplifies them, and sends the resulting electric current flow into a set of headphones, which convert the current flow into sound signals that your ears can hear.

Comment: So basically extra-low frequency electromagnetic waves, as you mentioned, are within the audible range? Could you provide a resource with more on electromagnetic wave frequency? Thanks!

Comment: They are in the audible range of *frequencies*,  but they themselves are not audible because they are *electromagnetic waves*, not *sound waves*. That is why you need a radio receiver to detect the radio waves and convert them into sound waves.

Comment: Oh! That's interesting! Would in this case a simple coil would be a radio receiver?